# How can I return the most reoccuring value in the given csv list?

Tags: python, list, function, csv

I asked this question before but the answer was not provided as a function. I've tried to put in into a dunction but it didn't work so I'm asking again:)

So here is a sample CSV file that I have to analyze

```
1,8dac2b,ewmzr,jewelry,phone0,9759243157894736,us,69.166.231.58,vasstdc27m7nks3
2,668d39,aeqok,furniture,phone1,9759243157894736,jp,50.201.125.84,jmqlhflrzwuay9c
3,622r49,arqek,vehicle,phone2,9759544365415694736,az,53.001.135.54,weqlhrerreuert6f
4,6444t43,rrdwk,vehicle,phone9,9759543263245434353,au,54.241.234.64,weqqyqtqwrtert6f
```

and I'm tryna use this function `def popvote(list)` to return the most popular thing in **the fourth row of each list in the list of csv** which in the example above is `vehicle`.

**Explanation down below**

This is what I have so far

```
def popvote(list):
    for x in list:
        g = list(x)
        if x = max(g[x]):
           return x
```

However, this doesn't really work.. what should I change to make sure this works??

**Note: The answer should be returned as a set**

**Explanation**: So what I'm trying to return the value that is repeated most in the list based on what's indicated in (** xxxx **) below

```
1,8dac2b,ewmzr,**jewelry**,phone0,9759243157894736,us,69.166.231.58,vasstdc27m7nks3
2,668d39,aeqok,**furniture**,phone1,9759243157894736,jp,50.201.125.84,jmqlhflrzwuay9c
3,622r49,arqek,**vehicle**,phone2,9759544365415694736,az,53.001.135.54,weqlhrerreuert6f    
4,6444t43,rrdwk,**vehicle**,phone9,9759543263245434353,au,54.241.234.64,weqqyqtqwrtert6f
```

So in this case, vehicle should be the output.

Comment: This is a good use-case for pandas: `pd.read_csv("filename.csv", header=None)[3].mode()` gives a series of most common entries in the fourth column (unique in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Raw python approach, using `collections.Counter`:

```py
import csv
from collections import Counter

def read_categories():
    with open("tmp.csv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            yield row[3]

counter = Counter(read_categories())
counter.most_common(n=1)
# [('vehicle', 2)]
```

Raw python only:

```py
import csv

value_to_count = {}
with open("tmp.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        category = row[3]
        if category in value_to_count:
            value_to_count[category] += 1
        else:
            value_to_count[category] = 1

# sorted list of counts and values
count_to_value = sorted((v, k) for k, v in value_to_count.items())

if count_to_value:
    print("most common", count_to_value[-1])
    # most common (2, 'vehicle')
```

If you find [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) useful, then:

```py
from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table

rows = Table.from_csv("tmp.csv", header=False).into_iter_rows(tuple)

# this is where code generation happens, it makes sense to store
# the converter in a separate variable for further reuse
converter = c.aggregate(c.ReduceFuncs.Mode(c.item(3))).gen_converter()
converter(rows)
# "vehicle"
```

Comment: is there a way to not use collections and counter. Using import csv is fine but I would really like to refrain from using collections and counter. Is that possible?

Comment: If so, can you please show how?? I dont really understand :)

Comment: @jordanparker just edited the answer, see above

Comment: Thank u very much :). Just one last question. how can I put ur edited code under a function, like for instance, in my original FUNCTION def popvote(list). Because I tried putting it under my function but it doesn't work.

Comment: `def popvote(filename):` and then paste all lines you need

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by the comment, you can use `df.mode()` and typecast to result to set.

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", header=None)
set(df[3].mode())
```

---

```
Out: {'vehicle'}
```