# How can I modify my code to fit the function in order for it to run correctly?

Tags: python, list, function, csv

So I'm tasked with finding the most popular bid from a list of csv files like this

```
1,8dac2b,ewmzr,jewelry,phone0,9759243157894736,us,69.166.231.58,vasstdc27m7nks3
2,668d39,aeqok,furniture,phone1,9759243157894736,jp,50.201.125.84,jmqlhflrzwuay9c
3,622r49,arqek,vehicle,phone2,9759544365415694736,az,53.001.135.54,weqlhrerreuert6f
4,6444t43,rrdwk,vehicle,phone9,9759543263245434353,au,54.241.234.64,weqqyqtqwrtert6f
```

and I have to determine the most popular bid, which is found in every 4th element within the csv file...

so the thing that I'm gonna be looking for are the ones with (** **) around them, as indicated don below from the same example

```
1,8dac2b,ewmzr,**jewelry**,phone0,9759243157894736,us,69.166.231.58,vasstdc27m7nks3
2,668d39,aeqok,**furniture**,phone1,9759243157894736,jp,50.201.125.84,jmqlhflrzwuay9c
3,622r49,arqek,**vehicle**,phone2,9759544365415694736,az,53.001.135.54,weqlhrerreuert6f    
4,6444t43,rrdwk,**vehicle**,phone9,9759543263245434353,au,54.241.234.64,weqqyqtqwrtert6f
```

So from my example, the output should be `vehicle`

Look at my previous question here where I asked the same thing:
[How can I return the most reoccuring value in the given csv list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70256306/how-can-i-return-the-most-reoccuring-value-in-the-given-csv-list/70256538?noredirect=1#comment124195869_70256538)

Now with the help of a kind StackOverflow user https://stackoverflow.com/users/5387738/nikita-almakov , I was able to get this code...

```
import csv
value_to_count = {}
    with open("tmp.csv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            category = row[3]
            if category in value_to_count:
                value_to_count[category] += 1
            else:
                value_to_count[category] = 1
    count_to_value = sorted((v, k) for k, v in value_to_count.items())
```

However, when I tried to put this code under a function `popvote(filename)`, I encounter an issue which is that I don't know where to include the `filename` in the piece of code in order to get  the right output.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import csv
def popvote(filename):
    value_to_count = {}
    with open("tmp.csv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            category = row[3]
            if category in value_to_count:
                value_to_count[category] += 1
            else:
                value_to_count[category] = 1
    count_to_value = sorted((v, k) for k, v in value_to_count.items())
    return count_to_value
```

However, the output, which as expected is not being printed correctly. I know that I haven't implemented `filename` into the function, and the reason is I don't know where to do so, can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: Doesn't filename replace `"temp.csv"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
with open("tmp.csv", "r") as f:
```

to

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
```

Answer (score 2):

If the file `filename` ist the CSV file with the Values above, then you should replace the `"tmp.csv"` with `filename`. Then this function should return an tuple with the most popular bids on the front.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).